# The control of eigenvalue

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

$A = ({a_{ij}})$ and $B = ({b_{ij}})$ are $n \times n$ symmetric real matrixes whose eigenvalue are ${\lambda _1} \le {\lambda _2} \le  \cdots  \le {\lambda _n}$ and ${\mu _1} \le {\mu _2} \le  \cdots  \le {\mu _n}$ respectively. If $\left| {{a_{ij}} - {b_{ij}}} \right| \le \varepsilon $, please show that $\left| {{\lambda _i} - {\mu _i}} \right| \le n\varepsilon $.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [max-norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Max_norm) of the "perturbation" matrix $P := A-B$ is given to be at most $\varepsilon$. For a square matrix, [the max-norm is related to the operator norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Equivalence_of_norms) as 
$$
\| P \|_{\max} \leqslant \| P \|_{\mathrm{op}} \leqslant n\| P \|_{\max}. 
$$
Therefore, the operator norm of $P$ is at most $n \varepsilon$; i.e., all its eigenvalues of $P$ are in the interval $[-n \varepsilon, +n \varepsilon]$.

With a bound on the operator norm of $P = A-B$ at hand, [Weyl's inequality in matrix theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality) says that the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ cannot be too far apart. More precisely, the inequality states that for all $i$, the difference $\lambda_i - \mu_i$ is in between the smallest and largest eigenvalue of $P$; i.e.,
$$
- n \varepsilon \leqslant \lambda_i - \mu_i  \leqslant n\varepsilon,
$$
which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: A lemma may be help for the proof of Weyl's inequality: ${\lambda _{n - j}} = \mathop {\min }\limits_{{v_1}, \cdots {v_{j - 1}} \in {\mathbb R^n}} \mathop {\max }\limits_{(x,{v_1}) =  \cdots  = (x,{v_{j - 1}}) = 0,{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} (x,x) = 1} x'Ax$

Comment: @Adterram Do you want me to expand my answer with a proof of Weyl's inequality?

Comment: No，thanks. I just came across the above formula and it can lead to a proof of Weyl's inequality.